# AVCAM terminated due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, memory, terminate, avcam, pressure

Basically, my app starts with a `View` with a button that calls `AVCamViewController`. In the `AVCamViewController` I have a back button.
The thing is, if I run the app and repeat 8 times the following cycle: "pressing the button to `AVCamViewController` and pressing back", the app will terminate due to memory pressure.

I haven't changed anything in the `AVCamViewControler` class, is this supposed to happen? It is an Apple's sample...